# Java ComboBox Association with arraylist

Tags: java, swing, combobox, arraylist, enumeration

Please help me on the following code guys, I am trying to return arraylist elements(searched ports) from a method in class `SearchPort`. This would then be used in the corresponding class Communication, where the method `returnArray()` would be called to extract strings to be used for `Jcombox` options. But how do I go about doing it?  Please help.

```
public class SearchPort {

    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier;

    ArrayList <String> portFound ;

    public void listPorts() {
        portFound = new ArrayList();
        //Enumeration holds all port objects
        Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while ( portEnum.hasMoreElements() ) //while Enumeration contains more port objects 
        {
            portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement(); //switches through each port
            portFound.add(portIdentifier.getName());           
        } 
     }

     public String returnArray(){

          listPorts();
          for(int i = 0; i < portFound.size(); i++){
              System.out.println(portFound.get(i));

          }
          return portFound;
      }    

  public static void main(String[] args){
      SearchPort run = new SearchPort();
      run.listPorts();
  }

}

public class Communication {

JLabel jLabel1;
JPanel jPanel1;
    JComboBox Connections;

    public Communication() {
        JFrame commFrame = new JFrame("gec");
        commFrame.pack();
        commFrame.setVisible(true);
        commFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    commFrame.setSize(300,300); 

    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    jPanel1 = new JPanel();

    jLabel1.setText("GEC");
        Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14);
        SearchPort port = new SearchPort();
        String [] portStrings = { port.returnArray()}; //add found ports into array
        Connections = new JComboBox(portStrings); 
        Connections.addItemListener(null);
    jLabel1.setFont(font);
    jPanel1.add(jLabel1, BorderLayout.EAST);
        jPanel1.add(Connections, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
       /*Add Contents to the Frame*/ 
        commFrame.add(jPanel1); 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {       
        Communication GUI = new Communication();            
    }

}//end class
```

Answer (score 1):

1) you have three choices how to add Items to the [JCombobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), by implement

- [JComboBox(ComboBoxModel aModel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28javax.swing.ComboBoxModel%29)
- [JComboBox(Object[] items)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)
- [JComboBox(Vector items)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28java.util.Vector%29)

2) all updates to the already visible Swing GUI must be done on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

3) initialization for Swing GUI main method would be from [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

4) methods

```
commFrame.pack();
commFrame.setVisible(true);
```

should be last code lines in the `Communication class`

Comment: public JComboBox(Object[] items), how do i achieve that. I simply want combo box options to be my arraylist elements from SearchPort class

Comment: inside 1) `while ( portEnum.hasMoreElements() )`, 2)  `for(int i = 0; i < portFound.size(); i++){`

Comment: i am still unsure, because they are in two different classes, an example would help thanks